# Find the Lowest Lots - in MQL4 MetaTrader Language

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

To All Master / Coder

I have a question on how to find the Lowest Lots number in **`MQL4`**

Here's  my starting code :

```
for (  int T = 0; T < OrdersTotal(); T++ ){
       if (  OrderSelect( T, SELECT_BY_POS ) == true ){
             if (  OrderSymbol() == Symbol() ){
                   // Find Lowest Lots Code Here . . . . . . . . . . . . .


                   // ....................................................
             }
       }
}
```

I do not know how to start finding the lowest lots, everytime I use **`OrderLots()`** it show only the latest opened Lots.

Answer (score 0):

### `MQL4` works within certain "external" contexts
 - Broker Terms & Conditions being one such
 - Trade Management system being the second such <sub>... to name just a few</sub>

Having said this, your code happens to re-read **`OrderLots()`** from Trade Management **`db.Pool`**, where the record has to be principally SELECT()-ed first, so if your code does not explicitly perform **`OrderSelect()`**-driven navigation throughout the `db.Pool`, your `OrderLot()`'s responses would remain randomly dependent on other `db.Pool` "current"-record-pointer  activity ( which is more or less the know Russian Roulette, where you never know, when the arm will fire ).

So one shall rather remember to always explicitly control "current"-record-pointer navigation by adequately parametrised call to `OrderSelect()` before reading any piece of data from **`db.Pool`, the more if going to try to modify anything**.

---

### So, how to attack the minimum amount of Lots?

Well, **`MarketInfo( _Symbol, < MODE_MINLOT | MODE_LOTSTEP | MODE_MAXLOT > )`** is the set of function calls, that will save you.

Individual trading instruments have these values pre-set from Broker and these may differ also according to different Account Types / business offerings contracted between you, The Investor, and the Broker.

For this reason it is wise to systematically use a function, defined like this:

```
double   NormalizeLOTs( const double nLOTsREQUESTED, string aCcyPAIR = "" ){
         if ( aCcyPAIR == "" )   aCcyPAIR = _Symbol;
         return(  NormalizeDouble( MathMax( MathMin( ...
                                                     ),
                                            ),
                                   2   // --------------- BROKER_DEPENDENT, again
                                   )
                  );
   }
```

just to keep all Lot-sizing-specific operations to meet the Broker's Terms &  Conditions, because, otherwise your **`OrderSend()`** will straight fail to file at the Server side.

---

### Finally:

if not testing the lowest acceptable size of the Lots, but **an actual value, of the smallest Order, already filed at the trading Server and still exposed to Market**, the process has to traverse the records kept in the Trade Management system, in the **`db.Pool`**

```
double aSmallestLotSizeExposedAtMARKET = DBL_MAX;

for (  int aRecordPTR  = 0;
           aRecordPTR <  OrdersTotal();
           aRecordPTR++
           ){
       if (  OrderSelect( aRecordPTR, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES ) )
             if (  _Symbol                         == OrderSymbol()
                && aSmallestLotSizeExposedAtMARKET >  OrderLots()
                )  aSmallestLotSizeExposedAtMARKET =  OrderLots();
}
if (               aSmallestLotSizeExposedAtMARKET >  DBL_MAX - 1 )
                   aSmallestLotSizeExposedAtMARKET =  EMPTY;

Print( ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for the smallest OPENED order of the same SYMBOL of your chart:

```
#property copyright "Copyright 2016, joseph.lee@fs.com.my"
#property link      "https://www.facebook.com/joseph.fhlee"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()  {
    int viSmallestOrderLot = 0;
    int viSmallestOrderTicket = -1;
    for(int t=0; t<OrdersTotal(); t++ ) {
        if(OrderSelect(t, SELECT_BY_POS))
            if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol())
                if( (OrderType()==OP_BUY) || (OrderType()==OP_SELL) ) {
                    if( (viSmallestOrderLot == 0) || (OrderLots() < viSmallestOrderLot)) {
                        viSmallestOrderLot      = OrderLots();
                        viSmallestOrderTicket   = OrderTicket();
                    }
                }
    }
    if( viSmallestOrderTicket == -1)
        Print("No OPENED Order.");
    else
        Print( "Smallest OPENED Order: " + viSmallestOrderTicket + ", LotSize: " + viSmallestOrderLot + " lots");
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Will give you the smallest OPENED order of the same Symbol of the current chart. If there are multiple orders with the same smallest lot size, then the SmallestOrderLot will be correct, but the Order Ticket will be undetermined (usually the oldest, but is not guaranteed):
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Start with declaring the variable and give it a unrealistic high value

> `double lowestLot = 1234567890;`

Then, in the loop, check if the **`OrderLots()`** is lower than this value and replace the `lowestLot` value by this new found value.

> `if (  OrderLots() < lowestLot ) lowestLot = OrderLots();`

When loop is finished, you'll have found the lowest lot.

Comment: hmm..sorry i havent clear my question..what i mean is..when we dont know the lowest lots..how can we figure it out..btw thanks for your answer

Comment: Do you want to find lowest open price?

Comment: not the lowest open price..but the lowest lots from opened trades..example if theres 5 opened trades, i want to find the lowest lots from that 5 opened orders

Comment: Sorry, **`MQL4` does not work this way**. Your answer is principally misleading.